# How to read the cached data of another endpoint in an endpoint?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, rtk-query

So I have two slices created via api.injectEndpoints:

- Time slice -> getTime endpoint gives you the current game time
- Bomb slice -> getBombs

  - This slice recives a bomb location and an explosion time array via websocket.
  - The server only sends the new bombs array. On arrival I push them into the previous cache.

And here is the problem. When I push new bombs to the state I'd like to remove the bombs that are already exploded. (Their explosion time exceeded the game time).
I don't want to rerender objects that should not be visible at that point.
Currently I'm sending the current game time alongside with the new bombs array to know what to delete from the previous cache.
But this causes redundancy because in my game time slice **I already received the time**.

**How can I access the value in another endpoints cache?** Is this considered safe?

(I saw select function but where do I get the state function for it?)

Comment: Use either a good GPS, or learn to read and use the correct tags. As you see, "RTK" is about differential GPS.

Comment: Sorry about that, the tag seemed popular :D

Comment: ```ApiSlice.util.updateQueryData('NAME_OF_THE_ENDPOINT, undefined, draftCache)```
with this, you can modify data from an endpoint inside of another endpoint 
just pass the name of endpoint and you have access to cache data.

Comment: Well I used the updateQueryData but it feels like a really hacky way of doing that.. Guess I should create some slices to store the fetched data in..